# Using globals in objects

Tags: php, class, global-variables

I am trying to call a global variable in an object function as shown.

```
 $error_page = $GLOBALS['error404'];
  echo $error_page;
```

I've tried several methods suggested in the php manual and I'm getting no results.
I have confirmed that the variable is not empty when the function is called.

Can anyone suggest why I can't access it this way?

Oliver

Comment: Please show a full code example.

Comment: Is $error404 variable actually defined in the global scope? Perhaps it's defined in some file, that is included inside a function scope.

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
<?php

$error404 = true;

class MyClass {
   public function doSomething() {
       global $error404;
       var_dump($error404);
   }
}

$test = new MyClass();
$test->doSomething();

?>
```

and will output

```
bool(true)
```